# How to store pandas DataFrame in SQLite DB

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am unable to find good tutorial on this topic. I am having a pandas data frame, df as

```
Fu(varchar)  val

aed          544.8
jfn          5488
vivj         89.3
vffv         87.5
```

I want to create a database and a table and store the dataframe in it

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Demo:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('d:/temp/test.sqlite')
>>> df.to_sql('new_table_name', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
>>> pd.read_sql('select * from new_table_name', conn)
     Fu     val
0   aed   544.8
1   jfn  5488.0
2  vivj    89.3
3  vffv    87.5
```

Answer (score 5):

First creat a connection to your SQL database:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
```

Make your df:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=['aed', 'jfn', 'vivj', 'vfv'],
                      data={'val':[544.8, 5488, 89.3, 87.5]})
```

Then create the new table on your SQL DB:

```
>>> df.to_sql('test', con=engine)
>>> engine.execute('SELECT * FROM test').fetchall()
[('aed', 544.8), ('jfn', 5488.0), ('vivj', 89.3), ('vfv', 87.5)]
```

[Taken from Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)